# When two digit numbers in base $5$ are multiplied the result is $4103_5$. What are the numbers in base $5$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When two digit numbers in base $5$ are multiplied the result is $4103_5$. What are the numbers in base $5$?

Well given by two digit numbers in base $5$ I tried out the multiplication and tried to simplify.

$(ab_5)(cd_5)=4103_5$ or $(5a+b)(5c+d)=4*5^3+1*5^2+0*5^1+3$

Then get that $5^2ac+5ad+5cb+bd=5^3*4+5^2+3$

I notice that $bd=3$ so b=1,3 and $d=1,3$. Now this is where I'm stuck I don't see a clear way to get what the numbers should be without a lot of trial and error.

Comment: Seems quickest to simply convert to base $10$ and then convert back.  Otherwise, I'd just work out the unique factorization of $4103_5$...a bit unintuitive since we don't recognize the primes in base $5$.

Comment: You could also have $b=2,d=4$, so there's that. I think you should start with factoring $4103_5$ (which is easier to do in base ten, just because that's where we are used to factoring).

Comment: Yeah much easier thanks

Comment: both factors are less than 25 in base 10 so you should get a unique solution

Comment: Notice $4103 > 4000 = 4*1000 = 40*100$ If $ab*cd = 4103$ and if $ab \le 40$ then $cd \ge 100$ so $40 \le ab, cd \le 100$. So $a=c=4$ and $bd \equiv 3 \mod 5$.  The options get few quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\;4103_5 = x^2 - 4x + 3\;$ where $\;x = 5^2.\;$ Now factor it as $\;(x-3)(x-1).$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is cheating, but ... $4103_5 = 528 = 2^4 \cdot 3 \cdot 11$.

The pair of numbers greater than or equal to $5$ and less than $25$ that we can make with these factors is $22=42_5$ and $24=44_5$.

Answer (score 0):

Some divisibility tests
\begin{array}{ccl}
\text{n base 10} & \text{n base 5} & \text{Divisibility tests} \\
   4_{10} &  4_5 & \text{$4_5|N \iff$ sum of digits is divisible by 4}  \\
   3_{10} &  3_5 & \text{$3_5|10_5A+b \iff 3_5|A-b$}  \\
   5_{10} & 10_5 & \text{$10_5|N \iff$ N ends in 0}  \\
   7_{10} & 12_5 & \text{$12_5|10_5A+b \iff 12_5|A-4b$}  \\
  11_{10} & 21_5 & \text{$21_5|10_5A+b \iff 21_5|A-2b$}  \\ 
\end{array}

Since $4+1+0+3$ is clearly a multiple of $4$, then $4_5 \mid 4103_5$.

We find $4103_5 = 1012_5 \times 4_5$

Since $1+0+1+2$ is clearly a multiple of $4$, then $4_5 \mid 1012_5$.

We find $4103_5 = 113_5 \times 4_5 \times 4_5$

Testing $113_5$ for divisibility by $3_5$:
\begin{array}{c}
   1 & 1 & \require{cancel}\cancel{3} \\
   - & 3  \\
   - & - & \\
     & 3
\end{array}

So $3_5 \mid 113_5$

We find $4103_5 = 21_5 \times 3_5 \times 4_5 \times 4_5$

So $4103_5 = 21_5 \times 3_5 \times 2_5^4$

Examining the factors, it seems that the two two-digit numbers must be

$(2_5)^3 \times 3_5 = 44_5$

and

$2_5 \times 21_5 = 42_5$.

### Shortcut using hindsight

Note $(43_5)^2 = 4104_5$. Hence $4103 = 43^2-1 =(43-1)(43+1)=42 \times 44$

Answer (score 0):

Continuing along your route, where:
$$4103=(10a+b)(10c+d)$$
(notice all values are represented in base $5$ here)

All values will be in base $5$ throughout.

Notice that $40^2=3100$, which is less than $4103$, so $a$ and $c$ are both $4$:
$$4103=(40+b)(40+d)=3100+40(b+d)+bd$$
Now, notice that $\left|{b-d}\right|=2$ in order for the last digit in the product to be a $3$.  Since the order of factors is optional, and we know the first digits are the same, we will set $d=b+2$:
$$4103=3100+40(2b+2)+b(b+2)$$
$$4103=3100+(130b+130)+(b^2+2b)$$
$$4103=3230+132b+b^2$$
$$0=b^2+132b-323$$
$$0=(b-2)(b+134)$$
$$ b=\{2,-134\}$$
Since the digit must be between $0$ and $4$ inclusive, only $2$ can be valid.  For $d$:
$$d=b+2=2+2=4$$
Finally, since $a=4$; $b=2$; $c=4$; $d=4$, the factors are $\{42_5, 44_5\}$

Answer (score 0):

So $n_1 = 5a + b; n_2 = 5c + d$ and $(5a+b)(5c+d) = 4103_5 = 4*5^3 + 1*5^2 + 3$

$(5a + b)(5c+d) = ac*5^2 + 5(bc + ad) + bd = 4*5^3 + 1*5^2 + 3 = 21*5^2 + 0 + 3$

So $ac \approx 4*5$ which is a very large value considering $a,c \le 4$.

Note $40_5*100_5 = 4000_5 < 4103_5$ so as $(5a+c) < 100_5$ we now $(5b+d) > 40_5$ and vice versa.  So $a = c = 4$.

$16*5^2 + 5(4b + 4d) + db = 4*5^3 + 1*5^2 + 3 = 21*5^2 +3$

$20(b+d) + db = 5^3 + 3$

So $20(b+d) \approx 125$ so $b + d \approx 6$.

$bd \equiv 3\mod 5$ and $b,d \le 4$ so $bd \le 13$. so $bd=3,8,13$.

$13$ is prime so that is out.  $bd = 3\implies b,d = 1,3$ and $b + d = 4\not \approx 6$.  $bd = 8\implies b,d =2,4$ and $b + d = 6$.

So if an such number exist they are $42_5$ and $44_5$.

And $(4*5 + 2)(4*5+4) = 16*5^2 + 5(2*4 + 4*4) + 8 =$

$3*5^3 + 5^2 + 5(24) + 5 + 3 = $

$3*5^3 + 5^2 + 5(25 - 1) + 5 + 3=$

$3*5^3 + 5^2 + 5^3 +3 =$

$4*5^3 + 5^2 + 3 = 4103_5$.

And $42_5*44_5 = 4103_5$ or in base 10 $22*24 = 528$.